# Accelerate performance and speed of string match in R

Tags: string, r, performance

I have a performance issue I need help with. Please bear with me for the explanation:

I have a database of known Car Vin# and years (only first 4 lines of ~5,000 shown for ease):

```
>vinDB
>ToyotaCarola 2008
 IJDINJNDJIJKNDJIMKDK0897
 NissanAltima 1998
 LJIODJJNJDJNJDNJNJDJ7765
```

I also have a a .txt document that shows a unique DMV ID, a vin number, and a reference number in the following way (only 4 lines of ~55 million shown for ease):

```
>carFile
>#DMVcorrNumber33:1245638:563892:6378
 IJDINJNDJIJKNDJIMKDK0897
 +
 VIN#IDref6388546
 #DMVcorrNumber33:1245638:563892:6378
 LJIODJJNJDJNJDNJNJDJ7765
 +
 VIN#IDref2453663
```

What I would like to do is scan every second line (the VIN#) from my 'vinDB' file against every fourth line (starting with line two) of my 'carFile' file for a perfect match. If the match exists, I would like to output the name of the car, and how many times it is seen in the 'carFile' file.

So basically, I need this:

```
    Car          Year     NumTimesFound
ToyotaCarola     2008          238
NissanAltima     1998          1755
```

So far I have the following code, which works on a truncated 'carFile' file, but crashes my R program when I try it will all ~55 million lines:

```
VinCounter<-function(carFile, vinDB)

{
i=1   #index inner while loop
j=1   #index outer while loop
m=2   #index of vinDB, starts at '2' because first VIN# is on line 2
s=2   #index of carFile
count=0

while(j<=length(rownames(vinDB))/2)  # VIN# is on every 2nd line in vinDB file
{
  while(i<=length(rownames(carFile))/4)# VIN# is on every 4th line in carFile file
  {
    if(vinDB[m,1]==carFile[s,1])
      {
      count=count+1
      s=s+4
      }
    else
      {
      s=s+4
      }
    i=i+1
  }
 print(vinDB[m-1,1])
 print(count)
 count=0
 s=2
 i=1
 m=m+2
 j=j+1
 }  

}
```

So, basically, I would like to figure out how to:

1) Make the code above quicked and more efficient.

2) How to have my output be stored in a .txt or .csv file (because right now, it just shows me the output on the screen).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this relatively easily with `data.table`:

```
vin.names <- vinDB[seq(1, nrow(vinDB), 2), ]
vin.vins <- vinDB[seq(2, nrow(vinDB), 2), ]
car.vins <- carFile[seq(2, nrow(carFile), 4), ]

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(vin.names, vin.vins, key="vin.vins")
dt[J(car.vins), list(NumTimesFound=.N), by=vin.names]
#         vin.names NumTimesFound
#  1:     Ford 2014            15
#  2: Chrysler 1998            10
#  3:       GM 1998             9
#  4:     Ford 1998            11
#  5:   Toyota 2000            12
# ---                            
# 75:   Toyota 2007             7
# 76: Chrysler 1995             4
# 77:   Toyota 2010             5
# 78:   Toyota 2008             1
# 79:       GM 1997             5
```

The main thing to understand is with `J(car.vins)` we are creating a one column `data.table` with the vins to match (`J` is just shorthand for `data.table`, so long as you use it within a `data.table`). By using that `data.table` inside `dt`, we are joining the list of `vins` to the list of cars because we keyed `dt` by "vin.vins" in the prior step.  The last argument tells us to group the joined set by `vin.names`, and the middle argument that we want to know the number of instances `.N` for each group (`.N` is a special `data.table` variable).

Also, I made some junk data to run this on.  In the future, please provide data like this.

```
set.seed(1)
makes <- c("Toyota", "Ford", "GM", "Chrysler")
years <- 1995:2014
cars <- paste(sample(makes, 500, rep=T), sample(years, 500, rep=T))
vins <- unlist(replicate(500, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 16), collapse="")))
vinDB <- data.frame(c(cars, vins)[order(rep(1:500, 2))])               
carFile <- 
  data.frame(
    c(rep("junk", 1000), sample(vins, 1000, rep=T), rep("junk", 2000))[order(rep(1:1000, 4))]
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to learn the power of 'data.table' once and for all. Thanks again!