# Extracting the top match from string comparison in R

Tags: r, text, character, string-matching

I am currently using the 'agrep' function with 'lapply' in a data.table code to link entries from a user-provided VIN# list to a DMV VIN# database. Please see the following two links for all data/code so far:

[Accelerate performance and speed of string match in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391849/accelerate-performance-and-speed-of-string-match-in-r)

[Imperfect string match using data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763599/imperfect-string-match-using-data-table-in-r/21785476#21785476)

Is there a way to extract the "best" match from my list that is being generated by:

> dt <- dt[lapply(car.vins, function(x) agrep(x,vin.vins, max.distance=c(cost=2, all=2), value=T)), list(NumTimesFound=.N), vin.names]

because as of now, the 'agrep' function gives me multiple matches, even with a lot of modification of the cost, all, substitution, ect. variables.

I have also tried using the 'adist' function instead of 'agrip' but because 'adist' does not have an option for value=TRUE like 'agrep', it throws out the same

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, lapply(vin.vins, function(x) agrep(x,car.vins,  : 
x.'vin.vins' is a character column being joined to i.'V1' which is type 'integer'. 
Character columns must join to factor or character columns.
```

that I was receiving with the 'agrep' before.

Is there perhaps some other package I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom, this isn't strictly a `data.table` problem.  Also, it's hard to know exactly what you want without having the data you are using.  I tried to figure out what you want, and I came up with this solution:

```
vin.match <- vapply(car.vins, function(x) which.min(adist(x, vin.vins)), integer(1L))
data.frame(car.vins, vin.vins=vin.vins[vin.match], vin.names=vin.names[vin.match])
#   car.vins vin.vins vin.names
# 1  abcdekl   abcdef     NAME1
# 2   abcdeF   abcdef     NAME1
# 3  laskdjg  laskdjf     NAME2
# 4  blerghk  blerghk     NAME3
```

And here is the data:

```
vin.vins <- c("abcdef", "laskdjf", "blerghk")
vin.names <- paste0("NAME", 1:length(vin.vins))
car.vins <- c("abcdekl", "abcdeF", "laskdjg", "blerghk")
```

This will find the closest match for every value in `car.vins`  in `vin.vins`, as per `adist`.  I'm not sure `data.table` is needed for this particular step.  If you provide your actual data (or a representative sample), then I can provide a more targeted answer.